# setting default timezone in node js

Tags: node.js, timezone, default

i wanted to make the default timezone as Asia/calcutta in node js

i have tried process.env.TZ='Asia/calcutta'

Even after changing the timezone to Asia/calcutta
when i try to print today's date, i'm still getting UTC timezone.

> new Date()

2021-12-04T09:54:48.152Z

> process.env.TZ='Asia/calcutta'

'Asia/calcutta'

> new Date()

2021-12-04T09:55:33.447Z

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple way to get custom timezone in node.js

```js
const nDate = new Date().toLocaleString('en-US', {
  timeZone: 'Asia/Calcutta'
});

console.log(nDate);
```

Note: **This method has a critical problem IMO. Node versions < 13 only have locale data for 'en-us', which means it throws (in some cases) or gives the wrong date format for every other country. And in many cases, the date will look correct but day & month are swapped! A good way is to just use a `moment.js` and add/subtract the time required**